# How to define a morphology operation in a Neural Network as an activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, activation-function

I recently completed a task to study how to use morphological operation as an activation function for neural networks. But I had no idea and didn't know how to use keras for custom functionality. Can anyone provide Suggestions or related papers?

Comment: This [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00109.pdf) might be helpful for you query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if morphological operations will work as activation function. I don't think so.
I think you should use or combine morphological operations like dilation and erosion, and, after that, use a ReLU or softmax layer as activation function.

Morphological operations are available in tensorflow, and you can call them in your Keras application.

Reference links:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dilation2d
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/erosion2d

Comment: Thank you very much. I also think the morphological operations cannot work as an activation function.